# Dart Linter: library_private_types_in_public_api

Tags: flutter, dart, linter

I'm new to Dart/Flutter and working on correcting some linting errors I'm getting in my code. The error library_private_types_in_public_api is flagged by the flowing line of code:

```
_ActiveEstimateListScreenState createState() =>
      _ActiveEstimateListScreenState(estimates: estimates);
```

After reviewing the FLutter Github I see that this should be correct to:

```
<State>ActiveEstimateListScreen createState() =>
      _ActiveEstimateListScreenState(estimates: estimates);
```

But I am still getting the following error:

[image]

And here is the surrounding code for reference.

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is this correct `<State>ActiveEstimateListScreen createState() =>
      _ActiveEstimateListScreenState(estimates: estimates)`? It should be like this `State<ActiveEstimateListScreen> create() => _ActiveEstimateListScreenState(estimates: estimates)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.